# Short date to long date

Tags: date, vbscript, wsh

I want to display the date in a custom format. For example, the date `18-8-2015` should be displayed as `"18-August-2015"`. I tried several times but it only shows the month itself.

```vb
givenDate= "14-August-15"
'DD = Day (givenDate)
MsgBox DD
MM = Month (givenDate)
'MsgBox MM
YY = Year (givenDate)
'MsgBox YY 
SysDate = DD&"/"&MM&"/"&YY

Wscript.Echo MonthName(Date("18-8-2015"))

'MsgBox(FormatDateTime(SysDate,1))
```

Comment: What shows "only the month itself"? The code you posted should give you an empty message box and an error 450.

Comment: Your question is how to display 18-August-2015 if givenDate = 18-08-2015?

Comment: meaning that instead of displaying 18-August-2015, it just display August only. I want it to display full date

Comment: @Syahirah You *have* a full date (18-August-2015), so you'd just need to display that to get a full date. Do you want a different format? If so, what should the output look like exactly?

Answer (score 1):

You can extract the individual date components and reassemble them yourself or, better yet, you can take advantage of a .NET library, as shown below:

```
Dim dt
dt = #2015/8/14#    ' Date literal for August 14, 2015

With CreateObject("System.Text.StringBuilder")
    WScript.Echo .AppendFormat("{0:dd-MMMM-yyyy}", dt).ToString()
End With
```

Output:

```
14-August-2015
```

See [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8kb3ddd4(v=vs.110).aspx) for the list of date format specifiers.

Comment: Nice one @Bond! Never realised you use .NET like that!

Answer (score 0):

```
MsgBox Now       & vbCR & FormatDateTime( Now,       vbLongDate)  'general usage: today
MsgBox givenDate & vbCR & FormatDateTime( givenDate, vbLongDate)  ' your case
```

Read [FormatDateTime Function](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8aebkz6s(v=vs.84).aspx): Returns an expression formatted as a date or time.

Syntax: `FormatDateTime(Date[, NamedFormat])`

Arguments:

- `Date` Required. Date expression to be formatted.
- `NamedFormat` Optional. Numeric value that indicates the date/time format used. If omitted, `vbGeneralDate` is used.

The `NamedFormat` argument has the following settings:

- `Constant        Value :` Description
- `vbGeneralDate   0     :` Display a date and/or time. If there is a date part, display it as a short date. If there is a time part, display it as a long time. If present, both parts are displayed.
- `vbLongDate      1     :` Display a date using the long date format specified in your computer's regional settings.
- `vbShortDate     2     :` Display a date using the short date format specified in your computer's regional settings.
- `vbLongTime      3     :` Display a time using the time format specified in your computer's regional settings.
- `vbShortTime     4     :` Display a time using the 24-hour format (hh:mm).